# Add the parent product name to each cart item names in WooCommerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, cart, product

I Would like to display the parent product name with child product name (cart item) in cart page, for my **grouped products**.
I am selecting Parent product data as grouped product under linked product -> Grouped products adding child product.

The code from template **`cart.php`**:

```
echo apply_filters( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $product_permalink ), $_product->get_name() ), $cart_item, $cart_item_key )
```

**This is what I would like for each cart item:**

> Parent Product > Child Product

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**UPDATED on 2018-02**

> **Is not possible in a classic way** to get the parent grouped product name or the grouped product ID **as they don't exist in cart object!**

The way is **to include the grouped product id** in cart object when a product is added to cart using a custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_add_cart_item_data`** action hook (only grouped product id will be added as custom data in cart object).

Then to display the parent grouped product name with the current cart item name we use another custom function hooked in **`woocommerce_cart_item_name`** filter hook.

See this update: [Display parent grouped product name in Woocommerce orders details](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48907055/display-parent-grouped-product-name-in-woocommerce-orders-details/48917819#48917819)

So the final code is:

```
// Adding the grouped product ID custom hidden field data in Cart object
add_filter( 'woocommerce_add_cart_item_data', 'save_custom_fields_data_to_cart', 10, 2 );
function save_custom_fields_data_to_cart( $cart_item_data, $product_id ) {

    if( ! empty( $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] ) && $product_id != $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'] ) {
        $cart_item_data['custom_data']['grouped_product_id'] = $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'];
        $data['grouped_product_id'] = $_REQUEST['add-to-cart'];

        // below statement make sure every add to cart action as unique line item
        $cart_item_data['custom_data']['unique_key'] = md5( microtime().rand() );
        WC()->session->set( 'custom_data', $data );
    }
    return $cart_item_data;
}


// Add the parent grouped product name to cart items names
add_filter( 'woocommerce_cart_item_name', 'custom_product_title_name', 10, 3 );
function custom_product_title_name( $cart_item_name, $cart_item, $cart_item_key ){
    // Only in cart and checkout pages
    if ( is_cart() || is_checkout() )
    {
        // The product object from cart item
        $product = $cart_item['data'];
        $product_permalink = $product->is_visible() ? $product->get_permalink( $cart_item ) : '';

        // The parent product name and data
        if( ! empty( $cart_item['custom_data']['grouped_product_id'] ) ){
            $group_prod_id = $cart_item['custom_data']['grouped_product_id'];
            $group_prod = wc_get_product($group_prod_id);
            if ( ! $group_prod->is_type( 'grouped' ) ) return $cart_item_name;
            $parent_product_name = $group_prod->get_name();
            $group_prod_permalink = $group_prod->is_visible() ? $group_prod->get_permalink() : '';

            if ( ! $product_permalink )
                return $parent_product_name . ' > ' . $product->get_name();
            else
                return sprintf( '<a href="%s">%s</a> > <a href="%s">%s</a>', esc_url( $group_prod_permalink ), $parent_product_name, esc_url( $product_permalink ), $product->get_name() );
        }
        else
            return $cart_item_name;
    }
    else
        return $cart_item_name;
}
```

Code goes in function.php file of your active child theme (or theme) or also in any plugin file.

This code is tested and works for WooCommerce version 3+

You will get this:

[image]

> **NOTE:** The grouped product name has it's own permalink

Comment: @Asher A new version: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48907055/display-parent-grouped-product-name-in-woocommerce-orders-details/48917819#48917819